# ASP.NET Repeater Not Outputting HTML Expectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in which I want to show adverts. My problem was whether the repeater contained an URL, if it did wrap the image in a hyperlink, if not just show an image. To do this I used OnItemDataBound.

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <!-- Advert column -->
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_Adverts" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_Adverts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_Adverts_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row advert_row">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAds" runat="server">
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

On ItemDataBound I guessed it was the best way to check if the url existed and show a hyperlink. I tried hiding the hyperlink using Javascript but it hid the image as well.

ItemDataBound

```
protected void rpt_Adverts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Get this data item as a datarow
    DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

    //Get the url
    string url = drv.Row["url"].ToString();

    //Check if there is an url
    if (url.Length > 0)
    {
        //Create a hyperlink with an image
        HyperLink hlAdvert = new HyperLink()
        {
            ImageUrl = Resources.Main.Url + "/images/ads/" + drv.Row["img"],
            NavigateUrl = drv.Row["url"].ToString(),
            Target = "_blank",
            ToolTip = "Visit",
        };

        //Add nofollow attribute to this hyperlink
        hlAdvert.Attributes.Add("rel", "nofollow");

        //Add this image link to the advert panel
        pnl_Adverts.Controls.Add(hlAdvert);
    }
    else
    {
        //Create an image
        Image imgAd = new Image()
        {
            ImageUrl = Resources.Main.Url + "/images/ads/" + drv.Row["img"],
            AlternateText = "Advert"
        };

        //Add the image to the advert panel
        pnl_Adverts.Controls.Add(imgAd);
    }
}
```

This is how it outputted, I'm not sure why but it didn't add the hyperlinks to the panel even though I specifically added the hyperlink control to the ASP panel.

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <!-- Advert column -->
    <div id="pnl_Adverts">

        <div class="row advert_row">
            <div id="rpt_Adverts_pnlAds_0">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row advert_row">
            <div id="rpt_Adverts_pnlAds_1">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a title="Visit" rel="nofollow" href="/advertising" target="_blank">
            <img title="Visit" src="/images/ads/advertise_here.png" alt="" /></a><a title="Visit" rel="nofollow" href="/advertising" target="_blank"><img title="Visit" src="/images/ads/advertise_here.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I am expecting.

```
<div class="col-12 text-center">
    <!-- Advert column -->
    <div id="pnl_Adverts">
        <div class="row advert_row">
            <div id="rpt_Adverts_pnlAds_0">
                <a title="Visit" rel="nofollow" href="/advertising" target="_blank">
                    <img title="Visit" src="/images/ads/advertise_here.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row advert_row">
            <div id="rpt_Adverts_pnlAds_1">
                <a title="Visit" rel="nofollow" href="/advertising" target="_blank">
                    <img title="Visit" src="/images/ads/advertise_here.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are not adding the control to panel (pnlAds) inside repeater but the panel wrapper around the repeater. What you could do is use image control in repeater and show/hide it from your codebehind based on URL.

Comment: Yes wrong panel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are targeting the wrong `Panel` to add your HyperLinks.
You need Panel `pnlAds`. So use FindControl in the ItemDataBound event and use the correct one.

```
protected void rpt_Adverts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnl = e.Item.FindControl("pnlAds") as Panel;

    if (url.Length > 0)
    {
        pnl.Controls.Add(hlAdvert);
    }
    else
    {
        pnl.Controls.Add(imgAd);
    }
}
```